# How to select specific column from model while using eager loading : laravel

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have successfully retrieved data using eager loading as following:

```
$var = Question::with(['asker'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','username');
    }])->get();
```

The problem is that I am unable to choose specific columns from the model `Question`. I have tried the following:

```
$var = Question::select('q_id','title')->with(['asker'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','username');
    }])->get();

$var = Question::with(['asker'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','username');
    }])->get(['q_id','title']);
```

In both cases, it returned `null` value for `asker` while choosing `q_id` and `title`.

Comment: What does your Question model look like? It might be helpful to see the relationship between the question and the asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to include the foreign key while selecting data from the model.

```
$var = Question::select('q_id','title','askedby')->with(['asker'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}])->get();
```

The extra field 'askedby' had to be included. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: So, you didn't actually try my code, but said it didn't work. `select` for `Question` model was removed so my code should work.

Comment: not really. I tried then the error stated as askedby is not found in the TABLE(i also tried the other key) and then thought including it in the select statement.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to select foreign key, so Eloquent could find relation:

```
$var = Question::with(['asker' => function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'username', 'question_id');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Do you get `null` for relation? Does it work if you remove the closure? Is `question_id` correct name of foreign key?

Comment: yeah null for ralation and it works and askedby is the foreign key. Thanks for the effort.